# Select/Unselect All checkbox in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement select/unselect all functionality in reactJs but couldn't make it happen.

I have made select/unselect all main header checkbox functional and the single elements can also be selected or unselected.

**My work link:** [image: Edit m3nqw70m59]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class Box extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            allChecked: false,
            list: [
                {id:1, name: "item1", isChecked: false},
                {id:2, name: "item2", isChecked: false},
                {id:3, name: "item3", isChecked: false},
            ],
        };
    }

handleChange = (e) => {
    let list =  this.state.list;
    let allChecked = this.state.allChecked;
    if(e.target.value === "checkAll"){
        list.forEach(item => {
            item.isChecked = e.target.checked;
            allChecked = e.target.checked;
        });
    }
    else{
        list.find( item => item.name === e.target.name).isChecked = e.target.checked;
    }
    this.setState({list:list, allChecked: allChecked});
}

renderList = () => {
    return this.state.list.map(item =>
        <div>
            <input key={item.id} type="checkbox" name={item.name} value={item.name} checked={item.isChecked} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <label>{item.name}</label>
        </div>
    )
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" 
            value="checkAll" 
            checked={this.state.allChecked} 
            onChange={this.handleChange} />Check all
            <br/>
            {this.renderList()}
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Box/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

To be straight forward, i want this (https://jsfiddle.net/52uny55w/) type of functionality using the plain Javascript but not with the jquery for some reasons.

Comment: I try your code, all work. Where is the problems ?

Comment: @Wicak i want that **CheckAll** checkbox also to be checked, when i check all those items and  want that **CheckAll** checkbox also to be un-checked when i uncheck if i uncheck one of the items.

Comment: That code was missing in Codesandbox, I just recreated the same for reference.

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-curie-75u6d?file=/src/App.js:395-833

Comment: does anyone have a working example with buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved the problem at https://codesandbox.io/s/vvxpny4xq3

```
  handleChange = e => {
    let itemName = e.target.name;
    let checked = e.target.checked;
    this.setState(prevState => {
      let { list, allChecked } = prevState;
      if (itemName === "checkAll") {
        allChecked = checked;
        list = list.map(item => ({ ...item, isChecked: checked }));
      } else {
        list = list.map(item =>
          item.name === itemName ? { ...item, isChecked: checked } : item
        );
        allChecked = list.every(item => item.isChecked);
      }
      return { list, allChecked };
    });
  };
```

A few things to note.

1) I have updated the checkAll button to have a `name` property to ensure consistency

2) If modifying the existing state, use the new functional syntax

3) Destructure the objects and do not mutate them in place if possible. You could use `map` instead of forEach and use spread operator to modify the object without mutating.

Comment: Hello there, thank you very much for your contribution. And thank you for that **function setState()**  recommendation and **.map()**  method recommendation.I accept your answer. Thank you again.