# How do I add a select all checkbox and add a checkbox for every option shown?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs

I was trying to add a select all check box and a checkbox for each and every row of countries listed.  I am getting a checkbox but I am not understanding how to get the checkbox in every row. I am quite new to this and need to implement a simple search bar with a select all box and a checkbox for every row using controlled elements. Thanks!

```js
import React, { Component, useCallback, useState  } from "react";


import {
  Button,
  Input,
  Footer,
  Card,
  CardBody,
  CardImage,
  CardTitle,
  CardText
} from "mdbreact";

import blankImg from "./blank.gif";

import "./style.css";
import "./flags.min.css";

import countriesList from "./countries.json";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    search: ""
  };

  handleClick = () => { this.setState({ search: ""}); }

  renderCountry = country => {
    const { search } = this.state;
    var code = country.code.toLowerCase();
  function toggle(source) {
      checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo');
      for(var checkbox in checkboxes)
        checkbox.checked = source.checked;
    }
    
   
    return (
      <div className="col-md-3" style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}>
        <Card>
          <CardBody>
            <p className="">
              <img
                src={blankImg}
                className={"flag flag-" + code}
                alt={country.name}
              />
            </p>
            <CardTitle title={country.name}>
              {country.name.substring(0, 15)}
              {country.name.length > 15 && "..."}
            </CardTitle>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  };

  onchange = e => {
    this.setState({ search: e.target.value });
  };
  
  

  render() {
    const { search } = this.state;
    const filteredCountries = countriesList.filter(country => {
      return country.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });
   

    return (
      <div className="flyout">
        <main style={{ marginTop: "4rem" }}>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
             
              <div className="col">
                
                <Input
                  label="Search Country"
                  icon="search"
                  onChange={this.onchange}
                />
                
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}> Click to clear</button>
                <input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Toggle All<br/>
              </div>
              <div className="col" />
            </div>
            <div className="row">
            <input type="checkbox"></input>
              {filteredCountries.map(country => {
                return this.renderCountry(country);
              })} <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar1"> Bar 1</input>
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
        <Footer color="indigo">
          <p className="footer-copyright mb-0">
            &copy; {new Date().getFullYear()} Copyright
          </p>
        </Footer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I would think the checkbox needs to go in the `map` (or the `renderCountry` function)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Where exactly would you say it should go? Also, am I implementing it the right way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select/Unselect All checkbox in reactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54546096/select-unselect-all-checkbox-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

Here I wrote working example, where you can see the data flow. All state we have in `CountryList`. And we provide `checked` value and `setIsChecked` handler to CountryItem component.  Then we have `allAreChecked` state, using it we check all or uncheck all items.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const countriesList = [
  { label: "a", checked: false },
  { label: "b", checked: false },
  { label: "c", checked: false },
  { label: "d", checked: false },
];

const CountryItem = ({ checked, country, setIsChecked }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>This country is {country}</h2>
      <input type="checkbox" checked={checked} onClick={setIsChecked} />
    </div>
  );
};

const CountryList = () => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState(countriesList);
  const [allAreChecked, setAllAreChecked] = useState(false);

  const checkItemHandler = (country) => {        
    setCountries(
      countries.map((item) =>
        item.label === country ? { ...item, checked: !item.checked } : item
      )
    );
  };

  const checkAllItemsHandler = () => {
    const checked = !allAreChecked;
    setAllAreChecked(checked);
    setCountries(countries.map((item) => ({ ...item, checked })));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {countries.map(({ label, checked }) => (
        <CountryItem
          key={label}
          country={label}
          checked={checked}
          setIsChecked={() => checkItemHandler(label)}
        />
      ))}
      <button onClick={checkAllItemsHandler}>
        {allAreChecked ? "Uncheck" : "Check"} All
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CountryList;
```

Comment: How can I implement this for my function which shows the countries?

Comment: you can look this working code, analyze it, and then implement the same logic.